# Selenium - closing invisible alert

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I need to use selenium with a smartcard (opensmc) and the firefox driver.
after:

```
...
driver.get("mypage")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("login")
# Here comes the enter pin window (popup)
...
```

The driver blocks. There seems to be a problem with the **enter smartcard pin** window sent by opensmc driver.
To get around this problem, I enter the key using the `xdotool`.

Now I get a `tryUnexpectedAlertPresentException` when selecting *any* element or switching to anypage:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("logout")
driver.get("http://google.com")
# each throws the tryUnexpectedAlertPresentException
```

On the other hand:

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss()
```

throws `NoAlertPresentException`

Anyway, every further `find_element` leads to `tryUnexpectedAlertException`

Could you please explain this behaviour and how to get around this?

Comment: It is better to get detailed info of site and dom details!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the site nor the dom, since the alert is sent by a firefox security device driven by **opensmc** which asks the smartcard